# Rails problem with humanize

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, actionviewhelper

I am trying to humanize the symbols that are the keys for a hash

`c.each_key{ |f| humanize(f.to_s)}`

but for some reason, i get an error like so

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'humanize' for #<#<Class:0xb5b77a4>:0xb5b6598>)`

any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you came from PHP ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this way.

```
c.each_key{ |f| f.to_s.humanize}
```